# Why does GridView not showing data on Paging Index Changed?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, page-index-changed

I have a GridView that shows particular data and records when I click Generate button.

[image: GridView Showing Records]

My problem is that when I click for the next page of the GridView list the Gridview will be lost, I don't think the data will be lost too, I guess the GirdView just doesn't show it.

[image: Index Changed]

Can you please help me with this problem. I'm not the one who first create this website and I tried all the things that I know for this problem, I also searched for a solutions in the internet with no luck. So I hope someone can tell me why is the GridView not showing after clicking the next page.

Here's the code for the `Page_Load`

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    userid = IIf(SessionHandler.UserID = "", User.Identity.Name.ToUpper, SessionHandler.UserID)

    V3Substance.Attributes.Add("onfocus", "javascript:if (this.value=='Substance Cas Number') { this.value = ''; }")
    V3Substance.Attributes.Add("onblur", "javascript:if (this.value=='') { this.value = 'Substance Cas Number'; }")

    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        V1Division.DataSource = GetDivision()
        V1Division.DataBind()

        V1BR.Items.Clear()
        V1BR.DataSource = GetBusinessRule(V1Division.Text)
        V1BR.DataBind()

        MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 0
        Panel1.DefaultButton = "V1Generate"
    End If
End Sub
```

Here's the code for `GridView1_PageIndexChanging`

```
Protected Sub GridView1_PageIndexChanging(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewPageEventArgs) Handles GridView1.PageIndexChanging
    Dim dt As DataTable = TryCast(GridView1.DataSource, DataTable)
    GridView1.DataSource = SortTable(dt)

    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
    GridView1.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Here's the code for `BindGridView`

```
Private Sub BindGridview(ByVal query As String, ByVal countquery As String)
    ViewState.Add("Query", query)
    ViewState.Add("CountQuery", countquery)

    Dim count As Integer = 0

    If Description.Text = "1" Then
        ValidateFamily(query)
    Else
        DataSource = dbHelper.GetRecordDT(query)
    End If

    count = DataSource.Rows.Count

    'GridView1.DataSource = Nothing
    'GridView1.DataBind()
    'GridView1.PageIndex = 0

    GridView1.DataSource = DataSource
    GridView1.Visible = True
    GridView1.DataBind()

    ExportToExcel.Visible = IIf(count < 1, False, True)
    Panel1.Visible = IIf(count < 1, False, True)
    SetTotalResult(count)
End Sub
```

I also tried to put this code in Page_Load

```
If ViewState.Item("Query") <> Nothing Then
    BindGridview(ViewState.Item("Query"), ViewState.Item("CountQuery"))
End If
```

But the result is a problem also, it shows the GridView data list when I click the next page but when clicking the Generate button it's like this

[image: Generate1]

or like this

[image: Generate2]

Please help me with this. Thank you so much.

**UPDATE**

Okay so I put this code in Page_Load

```
If ViewState.Item("Query") <> Nothing Then
    BindGridview(ViewState.Item("Query"), ViewState.Item("CountQuery"))
End If
```

Then I put `GridView1.Visible = True` to `GridView1_PageIndexChanging` and when I click the next page it shows No Record Found only even if it fetched the data already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've been doing this thing for a while now and thankfully I did it already.
It took me a lot of different approach and solutions that didn't help me at all but thankfully, this one is correct now.

Code for `Page_Load`

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
            userid = IIf(SessionHandler.UserID = "", User.Identity.Name.ToUpper, SessionHandler.UserID)

            V3Substance.Attributes.Add("onfocus", "javascript:if (this.value=='Substance Cas Number') { this.value = ''; }")
            V3Substance.Attributes.Add("onblur", "javascript:if (this.value=='') { this.value = 'Substance Cas Number'; }")

            If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
                V1Division.DataSource = GetDivision()
                V1Division.DataBind()

                V1BR.Items.Clear()
                V1BR.DataSource = GetBusinessRule(V1Division.Text)
                V1BR.DataBind()

                MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 0
                Panel1.DefaultButton = "V1Generate"

                If ViewState.Item("Query") <> Nothing Then
                    BindGridview(ViewState.Item("Query"), ViewState.Item("CountQuery"))
                End If
            End If
End Sub
```

Code for `GridView1_PageIndexChanging`

```
 Protected Sub GridView1_PageIndexChanging(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewPageEventArgs) Handles GridView1.PageIndexChanging
            Dim dt As DataTable = TryCast(GridView1.DataSource, DataTable)
            GridView1.DataSource = SortTable(dt)

            GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
            'GridView1.DataBind()
            If ViewState.Item("Query") <> Nothing Then
                BindGridview(ViewState.Item("Query"), ViewState.Item("CountQuery"))
            End If
End Sub
```

I add

```
If ViewState.Item("Query") <> Nothing Then
                    BindGridview(ViewState.Item("Query"), ViewState.Item("CountQuery"))
                End If
```

in `If Not Page.IsPOstBack` for showing the record when selecting again in the DropDownList and in `PageIndexChanging` for showing record when clicking for the next page.